# What does the " \' " means in the ng-style?

Tags: css, angularjs

what does the " \' " in the following code means ?

```
<div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }"
```

Why can't one just write

```
<div ng-style="{ cursor: row.cursor }"
```

The full code

```
rowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col
in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" 
style="overflow: visible"><div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" 
ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">&nbsp;</div><div ng-cell></div></div>',
```

I also dun understand why in the first ng-style the code uses \', and in the second ng-style the codes uses height directly without \'.

Codes taken from https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/994

Comment: `\` is an escape character. But given you seem to use double quotes around the string it seems redundant. This: `"{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }"` is the same as this: `"{'cursor': row.cursor}"`. However, if you were to use single quotes on the outside too then you must escape inner single quotes to prevent the string to end, similar to this: `'{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }'`

Comment: The full code would have been handy to see upfront as the initial example made the escaping of the single quote seem pointless. But with the full string now in the question you can see that the most outer quotes are single quotes and as such the inner single quotes must be escaped or they break the string.

Comment: Adding the main point last? :) The escape character is there to safe parse what's inside the matching single quotes. You can simply replace them with double quotes for the cursor and will be the same thing

Comment: really appreciate! @FrançoisWahl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\` escapes the single quote right after it.

Comment: Sorry dun quite get it. So is there any difference between the one with `\\` and the one without '\'? if the '\' just escapes the single quote right after it?

Comment: Shouldn't be, probably just for presentation purposes (albeit weird...)

Comment: err, something else, how did u type the \ in code format in the mini-markdown formating? I can't do it... :P